# html5 shopping cart recommendations

Tags: shopping-cart

I am building an html5 site for someone and I am wondering what the best option would be for a shopping cart. I want something that will be integrated on the various pages, not just a separate area for a shop, although we may utilize that option also. She has used ZenCart on her other sites, but perhaps there is something better. I am not a developer so the simpler the better. There is a lot of merchandise to list. Thanks for any suggestions you may have.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OpenCart](http://www.opencart.com/). Its easy to make websites using it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not a Wordpress site. She claimed she did not want Wordpress.

Comment: Thank you, I may try it.

Answer (score 0):

zencart is easy to edit ,even in code level.
but opencart is more powerful than zencart,especially in marketing and image manager.

so ,I also recommend opencart.

Comment: Thank you! I am thinking of trying it.